# Any composite keys limitations with EF?

Tags: .net, database, database-design, entity-framework, orm

Some ORM for .NET have limited support for composite keys. Stuff like relations, variant types and LINQ queries may or may not work depending on the case. I've even seen one ORM that doesn't even support writable composite key fields.

What of Entity Framework? I couldn't seem to find anything on Google suggesting I might run into some issues using such a db design.

Is there anything I should know before considering using EF entities with multiple keys? Or does it work just as well as it does with entities having a surrogate key?

Just so we're clear: I *did* some basic tests on my own. But being relatively new to developing with commercial ORMs, I'm afraid I might miss something. I want to avoid being stuck in a corner late in development, should the database designer decide to add tables with a particular key pattern that wouldn't be supported.

Comment: composite keys aren't the greatest idea to start with

Comment: @ratchetfreak I don't mean to reopen the surrogate key vs composite keys debate. As of now the thing is that I have little to no control over how the database is built. I have to live with that fact. What I really need to know is what challenges I will meet with using EF on this particular composite key issue.

Comment: I don't believe that there are. I've never come across any in a few years of using EF> However, a comprehensive 'No Problem!' can't be given because there may be some horribly complicated edge case where there is a problem. What I can say is that in my experience I have never seen a problem in this. The one problem I do know about EF models is that they really don't like tables without either a primary key, or a column that it can infer is a unique row identifier: this affects views; if it can't detect a unique column it won't import the view.

Comment: So if you have several composite UNIQUE keys in a table, but none is primary, and none is single-column, then there is a problem ?

Comment: Also, if some data connection between tables is established through a composite key that isn't the primary one, perhaps it will be impossible (or extremely difficult) to exploit this data connection directly using EF, even if the concerned entities themselves are "supported" ?

Comment: @ErwinSmout - not tried that, but I think it would be OK. Presumably it would pick one of the Unique indexes. However I always have a PK (usually int identity) on all my tables so I've not seen that situation.